# I am trying to use return value in this program but it won't compile

Tags: java

I try to make total scores and weighted scores into return value and the parameters are passed from the scanner console, and the return values are called from the static void method.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Grades {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        intro();

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        int totalScoreMain = totalScore(score, curveNumber);
        double weightedScoreMain = weightedScore(weight, score, curveNumber);
        double weightedScore2Main = weightedScore2(weight2, sections, sumScore);

        for(int i = 1; i <= 2; exam++); {
            System.out.println("Exam i");
            exam();
        }
        homework();
}

public static void intro () {

        System.out.println("This program reads exam/homework scores");
        System.out.println("and reports your overall course grade.");
        System.out.println();
    }


public static void exam () {

        System.out.print("What is its weight (0-100)?");
        double weight = console.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Score earned?");
        int score = console.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Was there a curve (1=yes, 2=no)?");
        int curve = console.nextInt();
            if (curve == 1) {
                System.out.print("How much was the curve?");
                int curveNumber = console.nextInt();    
            } else if (curve == 2) {
                int curveNumber = 0;
            }

        totalScore(score, curveNumber);
        weightedscore(weight, score, curveNumber);

        System.out.println("Total points = " + totalScoreMain + "/" + "100");
        System.out.println("Weighted score = " + weightedScoreMain + "/" + weight);
    }

public static int totalScore (int score, int curveNumber) {

        int totalScore = Math.min(score + curveNumber, 100);
        return totalScore;
    }

public static double weightedScore (int weight, int score, int curveNumber) {

        double weightedScore = (score + curveNumber) * weight/100;
        return weightedScore;
    }

public static void homework () {

        System.out.print("What is its weight (0-100)?");
            int weight2 = console.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Number of assignments?");
            int number = console.nextInt();
            int sumScore = 0;
            int sumMax = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            System.out.println("Assignment " + i + "score and max?");
                int aScore = console.nextInt();
                int aScoreMax = console.nextInt();

                sumScore = sumScore + aScore;
                sumMax = sumMax + aScoreMax; }

            System.out.print("How many sections attended?");
                int section = console.nextInt();
                int sections = Math.min(3 * section, 20);
            System.out.println("Section points = " + sections);

            weightedScore2(weight2, sections, sumScore);

                System.out.println("Total points = " + (sections + sumScore) + "/" + sumMax);
                System.out.println("Weighted score = " + weightedScore2 + "/" + weight2);
        }


public static double weightedScore2(int weight2, int sections, int sumScore) {

            int weightedScore2 = weight2/100 * (sections + sumScore);
            return weightedScore2;
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me to understand what I'm doing incorrectly? I don't understand why what I've pasted is not working.

Comment: Not even close to enough information - what does it do, what does it  not do, ......

Comment: What is the compiler's error message?

Comment: Your code really does not make much sens. Please try _much_ smaller steps, and build up progressively making sure you understand what is going on each time.

Comment: In the future, please step through your code to narrow down the scope of your problem, so that you can ask a specific question. Even though you have received an answer by a seemingly clairvoyant user, I'm closing this as not a real question, as it would apply to the majority of our community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem not to have understood the scope of variables, yet. The way your program is designed, the main method creates a Scanner object called console but has a reference that is only available inside this method. In order to use it in exam(), you would have to pass the reference in some way or make it some kind of member (or wahtever, don't try to fix things there, there's much more broken as it is). However, you most probably just want to create the object in exam(), because it is only used in that method.

It's the same with weight, score, etc. You attempt to use them in the main method, but at that point, they are simply not there!

You should try to start withan almost empty main method, add line by line and always compile and try to run it and see if it works like you want it to. If it doesn't, ask for help on that particular problem.

In the code you posted, there are so many errors that it is almost impossible to find a good point to start with giving advice on what to do different.

Comment: +1 for the initial attempt at discovery, leaving it as an exercise for the OP to fix these (and many other) errors

Comment: Where did you get a working crystal ball? I've been scouring e-bay for weeks, but they all look like scams to me. Thank you for the time you put into this.

Answer (score 1):

You never declare score, curveNumber, or weight.  Among a host of many other problems.
EDIT: Also, "i" turns into the undeclared "exam" in your for loop.

Comment: So, to paraphrase Owen Wilson's character in Armageddon, "Pretty much all of it isn't correct"

Comment: I did not go to the lecture so I dont really know how to use return value. I want to pass on the variables into the return value. how can I do that??

Comment: You'd better go to the lectures next time, your code is a complete mess.

Comment: I know I should....i have reasons..... But right now I have know clue how to make changes!...

Comment: Since you have multiple variables coming from one method, you'd have to use an array.  And you shouldn't worry about arrays right now.  So you're going to have to break up your exam method into multiple parts, with each part returning a different value (at the end of the method you would say `return weight;` or whatever variable you're returning).  To keep that value, you'd have to say `double weight = GetWeight();` in your main method.  And that all needs to go before you start using those values in totalScore.